# error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Error Message:

```
**Error Number: 2014
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
call allBarang('','')
Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/jualbarang/application/models/dbAll.php
Line Number: 18**
```

[image: Snapshot]

I don't know why cannot call 2 models in same function, I set function in `index()` because first page must have some models

Comment: There might be problem with your query logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php

CodeIgniter does not currently allow more than one stored procedure to be run during the same request.

The following method was added to the CI_DB_mysqli_result class:

```
function next_result()
{
  if (is_object($this->conn_id))
  {
      return mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id);
  }
}
```

Source: http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-758.html